# remain the position scroll for each the tabs using JavaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### i have three tabs i want keep position scroll when i transfer between them

Example: the first tab in the middle of the page when he moved to the second tab and pass it to the end of the page and go back to when the first tab I want her to be the middle (like before leaving)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<title>My App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/framework7.ios.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="views">
<div class="view view-main">
<div class="pages navbar-fixed">
<div data-page="home" class="page with-subnavbar">
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="center">Swipeable Tabs</div>
<div class="subnavbar">
<div class="buttons-row"><a href="#tab1" class="button active tab-link">Tab 1</a><a href="#tab2" class="button tab-link">Tab 2</a><a href="#tab3" class="button tab-link">Tab 3</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tabs-swipeable-wrap">
<div class="tabs">
<div id="tab1" class="page-content with-subnavbar tab active">
<div class="content-block">
<p>This is tab 1 content</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elementum mi quis felis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam ut commodo justo. Mauris vitae pharetra arcu. Sed tincidunt dui et nibh auctor pretium. Nam accumsan fermentum sem. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla sed orci malesuada, pellentesque elit vitae, cursus lorem. Praesent et vehicula sapien, ut rhoncus quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vitae mi nec lorem aliquet venenatis quis nec nibh. Aenean sit amet leo ligula. Fusce in massa et nisl dictum ultricies et vitae dui. Sed sagittis quis diam sed lobortis. Donec in massa pharetra, tristique purus vitae, consequat mauris. Aliquam tellus ante, pharetra in mattis ut, dictum quis erat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque elementum mi quis felis scelerisque faucibus. Aliquam ut commodo justo. Mauris vitae pharetra arcu. Sed tincidunt dui et nibh auctor pretium. Nam accumsan fermentum sem. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla sed orci malesuada, pellentesque elit vitae, cursus lorem. Praesent et vehicula sapien, ut rhoncus quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vitae mi nec lorem aliquet venenatis quis nec nibh. Aenean sit amet leo ligula. Fusce in massa et nisl dictum ultricies et vitae dui. Sed sagittis quis diam sed lobortis. Donec in massa pharetra, tristique purus vitae, consequat mauris. Aliquam tellus ante, pharetra in mattis ut, dictum quis erat.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="page-content tab">
<div class="content-block">
<p>This is tab 2 content</p>
<p>Ut ac lobortis lacus, non pellentesque arcu. Quisque sodales sapien malesuada, condimentum nunc at, viverra lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus eu pulvinar turpis, id tristique quam. Aenean venenatis molestie diam, sit amet condimentum nisl pretium id. Donec diam tortor, mollis in vehicula id, vehicula consectetur nulla. Quisque posuere rutrum mauris, eu rutrum turpis blandit at. Proin volutpat tortor sit amet metus porttitor accumsan. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut dapibus posuere dictum.</p>
<p>Ut ac lobortis lacus, non pellentesque arcu. Quisque sodales sapien malesuada, condimentum nunc at, viverra lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus eu pulvinar turpis, id tristique quam. Aenean venenatis molestie diam, sit amet condimentum nisl pretium id. Donec diam tortor, mollis in vehicula id, vehicula consectetur nulla. Quisque posuere rutrum mauris, eu rutrum turpis blandit at. Proin volutpat tortor sit amet metus porttitor accumsan. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Ut dapibus posuere dictum.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="page-content tab">
<div class="content-block">
<p>This is tab 3 content</p>
<p>Nulla gravida libero eget lobortis iaculis. In sed elit eu nibh adipiscing faucibus. Sed ac accumsan lacus. In ut diam quis turpis fringilla volutpat. In ultrices dignissim consequat. Cras pretium tortor et lorem condimentum posuere. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pretium egestas lacus ac laoreet. Mauris rhoncus quis ipsum quis tristique. Vivamus ultricies urna quis nunc egestas, in euismod turpis fringilla. Nam tellus massa, vehicula eu sapien non, dapibus tempor lorem. Fusce placerat orci arcu, eu dignissim enim porttitor vel. Nullam porttitor vel dolor sed feugiat. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas ac mattis odio. Sed vel ultricies lacus, sed posuere libero.</p>
<p>Nulla gravida libero eget lobortis iaculis. In sed elit eu nibh adipiscing faucibus. Sed ac accumsan lacus. In ut diam quis turpis fringilla volutpat. In ultrices dignissim consequat. Cras pretium tortor et lorem condimentum posuere. Nulla facilisi. Suspendisse pretium egestas lacus ac laoreet. Mauris rhoncus quis ipsum quis tristique. Vivamus ultricies urna quis nunc egestas, in euismod turpis fringilla. Nam tellus massa, vehicula eu sapien non, dapibus tempor lorem. Fusce placerat orci arcu, eu dignissim enim porttitor vel. Nullam porttitor vel dolor sed feugiat. Suspendisse potenti. Maecenas ac mattis odio. Sed vel ultricies lacus, sed posuere libero.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
<script>var myApp = new Framework7();            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>collapsible demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
$("a[data-role=tab]").each(function () {
    var anchor = $(this);
    anchor.bind("click", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(anchor.attr("href"), {
            transition: "none",
            changeHash: false
        });
        return false;
    });
});

$("div[data-role=page]").bind("pagebeforeshow", function (e, data) {
    $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.transition = 'slide';
});
});//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
 
<div id="page-1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 1</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>
                <p>Page 1 content</p>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>
                <p>Page 2 content</p>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page-3" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
                <p>Page 3 content</p>
        
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page-1" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-2" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page-3" data-role="tab" data-icon="grid" class="ui-btn-active">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("[data-role='tabs'] [data-role='navbar'] a").on("click", function() {
  const $domPre = $("[data-role='tabs'] [data-role='navbar'] a.ui-btn-active");
  const $dom = $(this);

  const hrefPre = $domPre.attr("href");
  const href = $dom.attr("href");
  const top = $dom.data("top")

  if (hrefPre.match(/^#/)) {
    $domPre.data("top", $(window).scrollTop());
  }
  if (href.match(/^#/) && typeof top === "number") {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).scrollTop(top)
    });
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).scrollTop(0)
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>collapsible demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="tabs">
        <div data-role="navbar" style="position: fixed; width: 100%;">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-3">Three</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><br>
        <div id="fragment-1">
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>
          <p>page 1</p>

        </div>
        <div id="fragment-2">
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>
          <p>page 2</p>

        </div>
        <div id="fragment-3">

          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>
          <p>page 3</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much .. Please tell me. Are you set up this code or is ready from the site jquery ???

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't understand what you mean. What's "set up" and "ready from" ? What's "the site jquery"? What's your native language? 说中文？

Comment: I mean your answer from your development or existing jquery api

Comment: Well, I built the answer with some jquery api.

Comment: please run my question after updated and give answer  on this

Comment: Hey guy, it's better for u to understand my answer and port it to your page by yourself. We r not free workers.